# Localhost Not Displaying Data

Tags: php, mysql, localhost

So I've created a php file and I'm trying to connect to my database:

```
    <html>
    <head>
    </head>
    <body>

    <?php
    $con = mysql_connect ("localhost","Densino","password");
    if (!$con){
    die("cannot connect: " . mysql_error());    
    }
    echo 'connected successfully';

    mysql_close($con);



    ?>

    </body>
    </html>
```

But when I go to the localhost there is no data to be seen. The php file is saved in the www folder of wamp too,.So i'm at a total lose.

I've even followed a tutorial on youtube, where that code is from and it works perfect for him.

Any help is appreciated.
This is what I see when I run localhost and click into the folder [INDEX](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MZFmU.png)

Comment: first, you should not follow a tutorial that still uses mysql, since it's deprecated and will be removed. Use msqli or pdo instead.

Comment: @Jeff depends on what version of PHP he's using...

Comment: Ok well I created a test page;

Comment: <?php echo "test"; ?> and saved it in the www folder..and it still doesnt show on localhost index

Comment: @jeff is right!! Anyway you are connecting with the database but you are not querying it in order to gather the data. So if you are expecting to get some help post all the relevant code please.

Comment: @k97513 if he's using a version of PHP that old, he is open to quite a few unresolved and unsupported security issues and might as well just post his server's root password online.

Comment: Ok, now I see the problem: nothing to do with database, your local webserver isn't working as expected. How are you calling the php-scripts? What server do you have?

Comment: @jeff I'm using wampserver

Comment: It looks like you are saving your scripts in the wrong folder. I don't know wampserver, so I cant tell where they should live, but I'm sure it's configurable in wampserver.

Comment: This-PC> Documents>Wamp>WWW still nothing...

Comment: I guess it should be in the folder `lessons` in www?

Comment: and what do you get if you only type `http://localhost` in your browser?

Comment: the lessons folder is in www...and when i open that folder in local host i get the blank index page. at a complete lose

Comment: the problem is that your scripts are in a different place than wampserver is looking for them. please search in the wampserver-documentation. I don't know it, so I'm afraid I can't help anymore!

Comment: Add error reporting to the top of your file(s) right after your opening PHP tag 
for example `<?php error_reporting(E_ALL); ini_set('display_errors', 1);` then the rest of your code, to see if it yields anything. Also make sure that all services are running with the **green light on.** Also, if there is no index.php file in that folder, then of course it will display nothing in that folder. It also needs to be accessed as `http://localhost/folder/file.php` and not as `c:///folder/file.php`.

Answer (score 0):

I created a new folder for my projects in WWW.. and I ran the folder in the browser: http://Localhost/projects

This created a new index file in the folder which allowed me to view my php scripts

Thanks for the help and guidance guys